# Restore pretty printed in chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome dev tools has built in pretty print, which is awesome! But I noticed there is no unpretty print button or way to remove the pretty print..

**Is there a way to restore from pretty print to orginal (minified, uglyfied) view in chrome in the same session (Without reloading the application)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not notice that the pretty printed code was actually opened in a new tab in dev tools.

The tab showing the pretty printed code is opened in a new tab with ending with :formated, so from the chrome dev tools the original code is still in a separate tab.